# SQL mutline cells convert to single line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some cells on a table that have multiline value, like (in col 3)
Hello,
this is the content of my cell
Thanks

I want to extract some value from a bigger table and import the result on Exceel sheet, but due to the multiline it dosen't produce a good result.

I'm doing the following:

```
select col1||';', col2||';', col3||';', col5||';'... from mytable where col1 in (1,2,3,4);
```

then I have each value followed by ';' that fine except for a cell where I have more than one line:

the result is like that:

```
col1||';'    col2||';'      col3||';'                       col4||';'
-----------  -------------- ------------------------------- -----------
1;           bla bla;       Hello,                          bla bla;
                            this is the content of my cell
                            thanks;
3;           12345;         blbl;                           blabla;
4;           3333;          dfff;                           ffff;
...
```

May some one can help me to get the col3 on a single line like

```
"Hello, this is the content of my cell thanks"
```

Thanks fro your support

Comment: If you have embedded line feeds characters, use the REPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE functions to replace them with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple:
    REPLACE(COL3,CHR(10),' ')

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot (it's allways easy when we know ;-) I do not have place where I can found all those commandes!